# Replacing cudaMemcpy2D with cudaMemPrefetchAsync

Tags: c++, cuda, unified-memory

I'm trying to do an **asynchronous** memory transfer (Host to Device) of data residing in **Unified Memory** in the same way that `cudaMemcpy2DAsync()` offers, i.e., using a **pitch value** for the destination (Device) memory.

However, to my understanding:

- I cannot use `cudaMemcpy2DAsync()` since it requires pinned memory and a Unified Memory block allocated using `cudaMallocManaged()` is not pinned by default and cannot be pinned manually.
- I cannot use `cudaMemPrefetchAsync()` because it only copies a continuous chunk of memory, whereas `cudaMemcpy2DAsync()` includes additional options to buffer the rows of my data according to a given pitch value.

**My question:**

How can I transfer my data, which **(a)** *resides in Unified Memory*, in **(b)** *an asynchronous manner* from the Host to the Device while, at the same time, making sure that the data is copied **(c)** *with the right pitch value*?

My current transfer using `cudaMemcpy2D()` looks something like this:

```
cudaMemcpy2D( 
    dest_ptr, dest_pitch,         // dst address & pitch
    src_ptr, dim_x*sizeof(float)  // src address & pitch
    dim_x*sizeof(float), dim_y,   // transfer width & height
    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
```

(As you can see, the pitch at the source is effectively zero, while the pitch at the destination is `dest_pitch` -- maybe that helps?)

**An additional hassle** is that I do not allocate the data that needs to be transferred myself and so I cannot apply the pitch manually without creating an additional copy of the data (which would be problematic).

**One idea I had** was to simply copy the data row-wise. However, this would mean a very large number of very small data transfers which sounds a bit horrible. In my example it would be 3,040,000 transfers of 304 bytes each.. but maybe that's fine on Pascal if the transfers are spread asynchronously across multiple streams..?

Any pointers/ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You may be confused about managed memory.  Since your unified memory is by definition unpitched, there is no point attempting to do any sort of pitched copy, if the source is a unified memory allocation (which it **always** is when using `cudaMemPrefetchAsync`).  If you want to copy from a **separate** pitched allocation on the host to a unified memory allocation, just use `cudaMemcpy2DAsync`.  However that doesn't appear to apply to your case, because you've said the data resides in Unified Memory.  You should clarify the exact way you allocated the source and destinations here.

Comment: Thanks for the info and my apologies for the late answer, I am only seeing your response today. 

I'm not sure I understand why a pitched copy into unpitched memory is impossible; it's just adding some padding while doing the copy, there's no actual difference in the memory itself?

Either way though, if a pitched copy is impossible then that's the answer to my question. If you would like to post this as the answer then I can accept it and close this question. (Though it has already been downvoted for some reason so it might not matter anyway.)

Comment: Unless you state precisely how the source and destination are allocated in your example, I wouldn't be able to provide any sort of answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you'll need to make a copy. Asynchronous copies with unified memory do not support pitches, because unified memory does not support pitches. You can either copy the prefetched unified buffer on the device into a pitched memory region, or you can copy the unified buffer n the host into a pitched memory region and then asynchronously copy it. You cannot satisfy all three conditions (a, b, and c) simultaneously

Comment: "Asynchronous copies with unified memory do not support pitches, because unified memory does not support pitches." -- Thank you, this was the information I was missing. Sorry if the original question seems to have been a bit murky!